# Eclipse SWT: display some text in the browser immediately without wait the end of execution

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to display a text in eclipse swt browser before the end of program execution, example:

```
button.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent() {
        //Trying to print immediately
        browser.setText("Example!");

        // sleep for test purposes, simulating the program execution
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // end;
    }
});
```

As exemplified above, the program wait all execution to print "Example!".

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread (even for testing) will stop the UI from running and updating.